# Nginx serving static outage page but not displaying images - they 502

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I currently have a web app running off Tomcat on port 8081 and I have nginx listening on port 8080 (iptables routing 80 to 8080) as shown below.
I am trying to configure an outage page to be displayed when Tomcat crashes for any reason.

```
server {
        listen      8080;
        server_name my.url.com.au;
        port_in_redirect off;
        root    /var/www/app/;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://my.url.com.au:8081; #not 127.0.0.1 due to Tomcat aliases
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_connect_timeout 150;
            proxy_send_timeout 100;
            proxy_read_timeout 100;
            proxy_buffers 4 32k;
            client_max_body_size 8m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        }

        error_page 501 502 503 /TemporaryOutage.html;
        location = /TemporaryOutage.html {
            root /etc/nginx/outage-page/;
        }
}
#there is also another server to handle https configured in a similar fashion.
```

When I shut Tomcat down to test this, I am getting the TemporaryOutage.html page displayed as exepcted, except there are two images embedded with the below syntax which are not displaying.

```
src="/Logo.JPG"
```

Checking ngingx access logs, both of these images are being accessed from my web app and are returning 502 errors:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - site [16/Aug/2018:16:33:34 +1000] "GET /Logo.JPG HTTP/1.1" 502 2175 "https://my.url.com.au/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-"
xx.xx.xx.xx - site [16/Aug/2018:16:33:34 +1000] "GET /Service.png HTTP/1.1" 502 2175 "https://my.url.com.au/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-"
xx.xx.xx.xx - site [16/Aug/2018:16:33:34 +1000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 2175 "https://my.url.com.au/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Is there any way to get that outage page to server those images in a static way without directing to the app while it's down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after posting the question I tried out a couple more configurations and found ones that work.
Turns out I had to include the image locations individually and serve them as required.

```
    location = /Service.png {
        root /etc/nginx/outage-page/;
    }
    location = /Logo.JPG {
        root /etc/nginx/outage-page/;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        root /etc/nginx/outage-page/;
    }
```